# ARP query and MAC addresses

Tags: networking, mac

Basically ARP broadcasts happen inside a LAN, asking for another host's MAC address for a particular IP address.

If the host is in a different network, how does the source computer know the MAC address of the other host? Also, if a source computer wants to send a packet to another host, after ARP broadcasts, if it learns that for this IP address the MAC address is not in its LAN, how does it request that other host's MAC address?

Comment: It's like David Schwartz answered. MAC addresses are only used for sending Ethernet frames (packets) over the local ethernet network. When communicating across networks your machine routes all the IP packets to your router, so it just needs the router's MAC address, not the remote machine's.

Answer (score 1):

If A tries to find the MAC of B's IP via ARP, and fails, B is not in its subnet.  A router is then needed, as the function of a router is to forward traffic between subnets.

The typical situation in a residental or simple office setup is that A will hand the traffic off to the default gateway, which will be the IP of the router on that subnet.  The default gateway will have been assigned to A earlier by DHCP.

*But*, since A knows what subnet it's on (since it knows its own IP and subnet mask), it usually doesn't need to do ARP lookups unless it's trying to reach another host on that same subnet.  And handing traffic to the router, if you are trying to reach something on the subnet you are on, will do no good.  So if a source host's ARP lookup fails for a destination host in the same subnet, the source host will assume the destination host doesn't exist.  And it won't even try ARP lookups on hosts on different subnets, it will just hand them to the router.

Nonetheless, there is [ProxyARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_ARP).

Answer (score 1):

> ... if the host is in a different network, how does the source computer know the MAC address of the other host?

Who says the other host even has a MAC address? MAC addresses are *Ethernet* things, not Internet things. A host doesn't have to know *anything* about hosts on other networks except their IP addresses. Addressing the final Ethernet packet to the end device is the responsibility of whatever device puts that Ethernet packet on the wire, which surely isn't this host (since it's not even on that network).

> And also if a source computer wants to send a packet to another host, after ARP broadcasts, if it learns that for this IP address the MAC address is not in its LAN, how does it request for the other host MAC address?

This doesn't make sense. The MAC address is clearly on the LAN since that MAC address just responded to its ARP broadcast. How could it put an Ethernet packet on the local LAN if it's not *on* the local LAN?

ARP queries and MAC addresses are a strictly local network protocol used among devices that have to put local packets on the wire for each other. A typical host uses this protocol to know how to address packets to its default gateway and to other hosts on the LAN, and those are the only devices it has to put packets on the wire for. The router, obviously, would have to know how to put packets on the wire for other networks.

Answer (score 0):

If a host is in another network, the source will not know the MAC of the host. To communicate, the source will send the packet to its default gateway to pass along.

This is done by sending a packet with the MAC address of the gateway, which is on its LAN, and the IP address of the destination host. The gateway will decide how to route the packet and re-send it keeping the IP address, but switching the MAC address to the MAC of the next hop along the network. This process repeats until the packet arrives at the destination.